# Month displayed in English after Ubuntu restart

Tags: php, date, zend-framework2, locale, ubuntu-12.04

I have a web application that normally displays the month of any date in french.

Even when I restarted the NginX server and the php-fpm server the date would be displayed fine in french.

But today I did a reboot of the Ubuntu 12 machine, and now the month of all dates of the web app, is displayed in english `Jun 2, 2017 5:11:27 PM` or `02/06/2017 17:03`

If I type in the `date` command in a shell I get the date in french though `vendredi 2 juin 2017, 23:47:59 (UTC+0200)`

Here is more info about the installed locales:

```
/var/www$ sudo locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
en_US.utf8
fr_BE.utf8
fr_CA.utf8
fr_CH.utf8
fr_FR.utf8
fr_LU.utf8
POSIX
ocatelin@sd-53310:/var/www$ sudo locale 
LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_TIME=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_NAME=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_ALL=

sudo locale-gen fr_FR.UTF-8
Generating locales...
  fr_FR.UTF-8... up-to-date
Generation complete.

sudo update-locale
```

I also restarted NginX but it did not help.

Here is some output from the phpinfo() call:

```
iconv.input_encoding    ISO-8859-1  ISO-8859-1
iconv.internal_encoding ISO-8859-1  ISO-8859-1
iconv.output_encoding   ISO-8859-1  ISO-8859-1
version 1.1.0
ICU version
intl.default_locale no value    no value
```

An example of a date `6/3/17 4:47 PM` (it should switch to 3/6/17) and her PHP code:

```
$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $action['date_reminder']);

$this->dateFormat($date, IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, IntlDateFormatter::SHORT)
```

The `IntlDateFormatter` is from `Start of intl v.PECL-3.0.0`.

Reminder: the issue showed up only after a machine reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Set locale in your application explicitly using `setlocale` https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php

Comment: My application has not changed since the machine reboot. It already had all the locale config in place. The issue popped up after the machine reboot.

Comment: Can you provide your `phpinfo` and piece of code that outputs English date then

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_FR');
```

---

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php